# ATmega32 communicating using RS-485 Modbus protocol

Tags: atmega, rs485, modbus

I am trying to read values from a meter (WDM303FDWA1) through an ATmega32. The communication to the meter has to be done with the RS-485 Modbus protocol.

I would like to know what IC I have to use to connect the ATmega32 and meter, and sample codes for the Modbus RS-485 protocol.

I am trying to communicate over only one meter and its Server ID is 1, Baud rate could be anything (default is 9600).

Answer (score 2):

The WDM303FDWA1 uses RS485 as the line interface connection and this means you need to interface the Atmega to an RS485 chip such as a MAX485. [Here](http://www.maximintegrated.com/datasheet/index.mvp/id/1111) is a link to Maxim's offerings on that device and here's the chip: -

[image]

- RO is received data out from the 485 and connects to your Atmega
- RE (bar) is read enable driven from your Atmega - it defines data
  direction along with DE
- DE - tie this to RE (above) and you have one pin that controls
  direction of data on the 485 line.
- DI - this connects to the data output line designated for your
  Atmega.
- A & B are the 485 line connections

If you look on page 8 of [this](http://larsentoubro.com/lntcorporate/uploads/product/Multifunction%20meter.pdf) document it details all the codes you need to send to talk to the device. It appears that you must send the "password" first followed by a function code, then the specific address of the data you want to read. The pdf file has that data.

As for the format of what comes back I can't help you with that - the document doesn't go into too much detail on this but, it does appear to be between 1 word and 3 words.

Neither can I help you with samples of modbus codes for use in the Atmega.

Comment: The samples would all just be normal UART usage anyways. There's plenty of examples of that already.